# Register / Config center HA solution across DC with replication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, consul

We have deployed multiple Java applications (spring boot based) in multiple datacenters. For better centralized management, we decide to register them to a same config / register center (Consul, Eureka, Nacos, ZooKeeper...). How to set up a config / register center with proper HA solution across DC?

I've googled for the solution for:

1. If a config / register center support HA across DC: Consul support WAN gossip protocol to communicate between datacenters, but no data is replicated (see [here](https://www.hashicorp.com/resources/ensuring-cross-cloud-high-availability-for-your-applications)), which is not I want. I need all the applications to be connected to the same config / register center cluster.
2. If a spring boot application support to connect to multiple register / config center: got no result so far.

Can anyone give me some ideas please? Thanks.